# Calculate $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} n (\frac{1+i}{2 \sqrt{2}})^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to calculate $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} n (\frac{1+i}{2 \sqrt{2}})^n$ ?

By the ratio test, the series converges, but I don't know how to calculate its limit.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}, |z|<1$$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $z$ gives,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$$ (because this series converges uniformly), now multiply both sides by $z$ gives,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^{n}=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$

EDIT: Proof that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ converges uniformly:

Consider partial sum $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k$ and $s_m=\sum_{k=0}^{m}z^k$

then,for $|m-n|<\delta$ $$|s_n-s_m|=\big|\frac{x^{m+1}-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\big|\leq |x^{m+1}|\big|\frac{1-x^{n-m}}{1-x}\big|\leq \big|\frac{1-x^{\delta}}{1-x}\big|=\epsilon$$

Thus, for a given $\epsilon >0$, choose $\delta$ such that $\big|\frac{1-x^{\delta}}{1-x}\big|=\epsilon$ and since that $\delta$ depends only on $\epsilon$, therefore, this series converges uniformly.

Comment: I hope it's not too late to ask this, but could you show me why this series is uniformly convergent. I'm familiar with the differentiation  of power seires, because I've studied formal power series before(discrete math ), but I'm only beginning to study series in analytical sense.

Answer (score 7):

Recall that $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \dfrac1{1-x}$$
for all $\vert x \vert \leq 1$ and $x \neq 1$. Hence,
$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} = \dfrac1{(1-x)^2}$$
This gives us
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n} = \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
Now plug in $x = \dfrac{1+i}{2\sqrt2}$ to get the answer.

Comment: So it suffices to use formal power series. I didn;t think about it at first. Thanks.